# Textbox inside an update panel not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have this in the aspx file.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
                       <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="In side update panel" onclick="Button1_Click" />            
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in code behind I have this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Label1.Text =  DateTime.Now.ToString();
    TextBox1.Text = "Some Text";
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

However, on `Button1_Click` I can see the time changes, but the `textbox1` does not refresh. I tried Triggers and various other tricks but nothing works. Basically, I want to refresh all the controls with in an Update panel from a button_click. I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you elaborate alittle more on "but the textbox1 does not refresh"? what are you expecting to happen? and what's is actually happening?

Comment: alejosoft - Thanks.  I expect textbox value to become blank.

Answer (score 2):

You don't change the TextBox value. :)

It's always "Some Text" because in your Page_Load you set it to that text. Try adding the time stamp or in your click event try replacing the text.

E.g.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Some Text 1...";
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

Use this in click event if you wish to make it empty

```
TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: I got it what you are saying. Actually  I have a dozen controls inside  an update panel populated NOT on page load  but  thru some other button click. Now when I am firing the  UpdatePanel1.Update();
I don't see those controls getting refreshed with blank values. Do I have to use string.empty for each of those controls?

Comment: Our main issue was that if a user populates textboxes in a panel and chose to close the panel with out saving any data; panel would  show old values in subsequent panel1.visible = true. So what we did was this:

<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert">
 <InsertItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
 </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

Formview1.databind() then clears all the values. 
As you would note that Formview1 container  has no purpose other than clearing the data.